# How to access variable values from jstl foreach to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, servlets, jstl

Hello guys this may be easy question but I m finding it quite tricky.
Scenario is I m printing all the values from the database table using jstl foreach.

```
<c:forEach items="${pal}" var="p">
    <tr>
        <td><c:out value="${p.pid}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${p.pname}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${p.pdesc}"></c:out></td>
        <td><c:out value="${p.pestd}"></c:out></td>
        <td><a id="popa" href="#">Allocate</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

And now onclick Allocate button I want that particular pid (i.e suppose there are 1,2,3,...,10 pid so when I click on 4th I should get the 4th pid as a value) in jquery.

But in jQuery when I try to get that value I always got last value in the loop whichever button I click.

In **jQuery** Section

```
 $("a#popa").click(function(){

     var input = $("<c:out value='${pid}' />");
     alert(input);

 });
```

and I also tried this

```
 <c:forEach var='lang' items='${paramValues.pid}'>
     <label><font color='#00CC00'><c:out value='${lang}'/></font></label>
 </c:forEach>

 but nothing works
```

Please Help me and guide me how to get the current value of pid on click in jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of each `id` attribute should be unique across the entire DOM. You're using `id="popa"` in a loop, this means that there will be more than one. When you try to select the `id` with jQuery it gives you the last one.

I would consider using the following approach. Instead of using an `id`, use a `data-*` attribute.

```
<c:forEach items="${pal}" var="p">
    <tr>
    <td><c:out value="${p.pid}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${p.pname}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${p.pdesc}"></c:out></td>
    <td><c:out value="${p.pestd}"></c:out></td>
    <td><a data-pid="${p.pid}" href="#">Allocate</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Then you can wire up the click event with something like this.

```
$("[data-pid]").click(function(){
  var pid = $(this).data("pid");
  alert(pid);
});
```

Comment: Can I please ask one more query how to alert pid aswellas pname, because when I data-name="${p.name}" I m getting warning message Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - End tag of element <a>
 - Undefined attribute name 
  (data-pid).
 - Start tag of element <a>

Comment: and getting output as undefined for pname

Comment: Glad it's working. You should mark this answer as accepted by clicking the √ below the voting controls (to the left my my answer).